# Empty list representation in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark DataFrame with a column named "Ingredients". It has some values like:

```
['banana', 'apple']
['meat'] 
[]
[]
```

I want to look at only the []. Tried this:

```
display(df.filter(df.ingredients == []))
```

But got error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an empty array to compare:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

display(df.filter(df.ingredients == F.array()))
```

Or you can check the array length is zero:

```
display(df.filter(F.size(df.ingredients) == 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding further to to @mck's answer, sometimes you have an array which contains only one empty string and it is also shown like *'empty array'*. Here's an example :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([''],)], ['value'])

df.show()

# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# |   []|
# +-----+

df.filter(F.col("value") == F.array(F.lit(""))).show()

# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# |   []|
# +-----+

df.filter(F.col("value") != F.array(F.lit(""))).show()

# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# +-----+
```

In this case `F.col("value") == F.array()` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try define like this code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
df = df.withColumn("ids",F.lit(None).astype(T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
```

the ids will stored as None
the `ids`'s dtype is `array<string>`

and query with `spark-sql` like

```
select *  from tb1 where ids is not null
```